# Export to RSS Feed

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I'm looking for class that can generate RSS feeds.

I'm thinking of a usage like this.

```
RssClass foo = new RssClass();
foo.addEntry("title", URL);
foo.Export("myexportpath.rss");
```

Has anybody seen such a class available for free usage?

Comment: Actually the System.ServiceModel.Syndication wasn't offering as much features as I hoped it would. I screwed that attempt and used a simple XmlDocument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace?  That contains a raft of classes that allow you to create, consume and manipulate RSS feeds and the like.

Comment: The .net framework is full of surprises. Provides all the classes I need.

Answer (score 2):

The .Net 3.5 framework contains [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) to quickly create both atom 1.0 & rss 2.0 feeds.